# autoresizingmask for height and width

Tags: cocoa, height, width, autoresizingmask

Im using cocoa in xcode 4.4 and I have a window which contains a view loaded from an xib file. I have created another view inside it which i would like to resize to fill the outer view whenever i make the window fullscreen.

I have tried using:

```
[self setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable];
```

And

```
[self setAutoresizingMask:NSViewHeightSizable];
```

And they work but obviously this only sizes the view in one direction. Is there a way of doing both?

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[self setAutoresizingMask: (NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable)];
```